# Angular translate toggle button text dynamically

Tags: angular, toggle, translate

I have this toggle that expands text which i would like to have in two languages. Normally i use  | translate and i add the translated text in json files (i18n), but this time it doesn´t work. Could i solve this with *ngIfs? TIA.

Here is my code:

```html
<div (click)="showMore()">
    <span class="cursorPointer material-icons align-text-bottom"> {{ !isReadMore ? 'keyboard_arrow_down': 'keyboard_arrow_up' }}</span>
    <span *ngIf="">{{ isReadMore ? 'lang1': 'lang2' }}</span>
    <span *ngIf="">{{ isReadMore ? 'lang1': 'lang2' }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ (!isReadMore ? 'keyboard_arrow_down': 'keyboard_arrow_up') | translate }}
```